# Is Delegation Pattern is a basic & crucial pattern? (excluding JAVA)

Tags: design-patterns

I've read that Delegation Pattern used to "Simulate multiple inheritance in JAVA". I wonder what about languages like Cpp which allows us 'multiple inhertance', is Delegation Pattern still necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "Simulate multiple inheritance in JAVA" you mean a class that extends another one and also implements one interface, and has a class variable of a type that also implements that interface, plus the methods that delegate.
For ex.

```
class A extends B implements C {
   private C c;

   public void Cmethod {
       c.Cmethod();
   }
...
}
```

Indeed, in C++ you do not need to do this, since you already have multiple inheritance. 
But there are a lot of other uses for delegation. 
For example, handling events in a GUI toolkit can be achieved using delegation: a component (say button) receives a message and delegates its handling to another  component. So a delegate is a valid concept in C++.

Comment: Ok, I got it. another question that I have is that if Delegation pattern is a basic pattern. I ask it because my teacher said that its not a basic pattern but there are Patterns (like Strategy & Iterator) that based on Delegation pattern.

Comment: Your teacher is right. People consider basic design patterns the ones described in the GoF book. I would say Delegation is something more of an OOP programming concept/technique then a design pattern.